# spyder/juypter not working after downgrading python

Tags: python, spyder, jupyter-notebook

I had to download my python version from 3.5 to 3.4 because one of the packages I needed wasn't supported in 3.5.  I downgraded the python version using the conda command prompt, and everything worked fine - got my package to install with all its dependencies and no conflicts.  But now when I try to open Juypter notebook or Spyder, nothing happens.  My IPython works just fine.  I'm thinking maybe i have to downgrade Juypter and Spyder, but I'm not sure.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `conda list`?

Answer (score 2):

After a day of searching I finally figured it out.
I initially used

```
conda install python=3.4
```

Bad idea - ended up having to do a fresh install of anaconda to get spyder and juypter working again.

What ended up working is creating a separate environment.

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
activate py34
... then install packages ...
```

This added spyder(py34), juypter(py34), and all its "py34 brothers and sisters" to my start menu.  Using these new shortcuts/environment, I now have access to the packages I need by choosing the appropriate short cut.  Yes, my start menu has extra python shortcuts now, but whatever - it works.

Just make sure Make sure you install the packages you're looking for before you close the anaconda console.  Perfect for installing `theano` dependencies `mingw` and `libpython`.