# Jupyter not working after downgrading Python (Non Conda)

Tags: python, jupyter

[There is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244117/spyder-juypter-not-working-after-downgrading-python) on addressing how to get Jupyter to link correctly after downgrading Python, but that is referring to a Conda install. My motivation for downgrading Python is the fact that [TensorFlow is broken on Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20444).

After uninstalling Jupyter and downgrading Python, I receive this error.

```
/usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/jupyter: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/bin/jupyter: Undefined error: 0
```

How do I link Jupyter and Python correctly to work properly?

Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: Any particular OS?

Answer (score 3):

First try to uninstall jupyter notebook:

`brew uninstall jupyter` (if you are on mac)

or `python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter`

then force reinstall jupyter by:

`python3 -m pip install jupyter --force`

Answer (score 3):

First, go the `cd /usr/local/bin/` where jupyter is stored.

This you do by typing `nano jupyter notebook`

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from jupyter_core.command import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Then you need to change from `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` to `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6`

This is how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**macOS:**

If you got Jupyter from brew, you can do:

`brew link --overwrite jupyter`

This will overwrite your `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` with a symlink to `../Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/bin/jupyter`

On my installation that file now looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
JUPYTER_PATH="/usr/local/etc/jupyter" PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/bin/jupyter" "$@"
```

rather than the earlier

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_2/bin/python3.6

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from jupyter_core.command import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

This fixed your exact problem for me.

It risks collisions with the `conda` environment I am sure and so I am not hopeful it won't break something else.